# Following a Kotlin tutorial in Android Studio: androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel import gives error

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, import

Been learning Kotlin and today I went to check out the "[ViewModel and State in Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state)" course.

In item 6, there's this code:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

@Composable
fun GameScreen(
   gameViewModel: GameViewModel = viewModel()
) {
   // ...
}
```

The import (when ALT-ENTER from Android Studio or pasted) gives an error. Precisely this: [Unresolved reference: compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQmO6.png)

The library is included as shown here. [Gradle build dependencies implementation showing lifecycle lib 2.6.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFxaO.png).

I followed all instructions from the start. Previous and after the error, all edits show error-free.

I've tried cleaning the IDE, rebuilding, invalidating cache.

I'm not sure what else to try. I have restarted Android Studio, but the problem persists. I'm thinking maybe there were some changes from Sept 2023, when the course was last edited, with the current version.

I'm on Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 4

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the dependency, as stated in the course wasn't entered. There's already one with lifecycle--the one shown in the screenshot--and my brain though it was the same.